# How to solve this integral $\int \frac 1{\sqrt { \cos x \sin^3 x }} \mathrm dx $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> **Question :**  $$\int \frac 1{\sqrt { \cos x \sin^3 x }} \mathrm dx $$

I don’t know where to start. I had tried many methods but they didn’t work.

Can anyone help me solving this ? 
Thank you

Comment: Could you show what you already tried ?

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%201%7B%5Csqrt%20%7B%20%5Ccos%20x%20%5Csin%5E3%20x%20%7D%7D%20%5Cmathrm%20dx%24&p=1) you can find that this integral was mentioned as an example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52109/references-on-breaking-integrals-into-logarithms/52110#52110).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: substitute $\text{u}:=\tan\left(x\right)$. Then the integrand will change to $\frac{1}{\text{u}^\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: Ahhh I got it. Thank you !!

Comment: @NovemberftBlue You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

1) Double angle formulas bring the expression to be integrated under the form :

$$\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)(1-\cos(2x))}}$$

2) Then use formulas :

$$\cos(a)=\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \ \ \ \sin(a)=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2} \ \ \ \text{with}  \ a=2x$$

where $t=\tan(a/2)=\tan(x)$ (thus with $x=\arctan(t)$ whence $dx=\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$).

Comment: Yeb ! I found the right way ! Thank you

Answer (score -2):

$\int \frac 1{\sqrt { \cos x \sin^3 x }} \mathrm dx$

multiply by $\sec^{2}x$
then you get

$\int \frac{\sec^{2}x}{\sqrt{\tan^{3}x}} \mathrm dx$

now let  $\tan x=t$

One gets $\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^{3}}}$

Now I think u can do  it